# Relationship of NSManagedObject to an NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsarraycontroller

## What I've got:

- **controller1** an `NSArrayController`
- **controller2** an `NSArrayController`. This has a parent relationship to an attribute of controller1.
- **controller1-2Tree** an `NSTreeController` and an `NSOutlineView` to view it. This shows the hierarchy of controller1 and the children of each item that it found from the parent/child relationship of controller2. This has been done by binding the two `NSArrayControllers` to the values and children of the tree.

## The Problem:

Everything in my situation uses core-bindings. Yet, unlike an `NSTableView`, the unorthodox set up of my `NSOutlineView` means that my current selection isn't passed onto my relevant `NSArrayController`. For example, if I select a child in my **controller1-2Tree**, it's an object from my **controller2**, but **controller2** itself doesn't register the selection change.

I have the relevant code to pick up on selection changes. I'm unsure of how to manually change the current selection item of **controller2** or **controller1** (although it's 2 that I need right now), based on knowing the current selected item of **controller1-2Tree**.

I've worked out how to isolate the currently selected object, I'm just missing the last step on how to relate this to the `NSArrayController` without iterating through it based on trying to match a property.

```
NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[controller1-2View itemAtRow:[controller1-2View selectedRow]] representedObject];
NSManagedObjectContext *selectedObjectContext = [selectedObject managedObjectContext];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I went the hard way that I was trying to avoid and got this to work by iterating through objects and controllers. I'm sure there's a better way than this.

```
if ([controller1-2view parentForItem:[controller1-2view itemAtRow:[controller1-2view selectedRow]]]) {
        // If not nil; then the item has a parent. If nil, it doesn't and isn't selectable.
        NSManagedObject *selectedProject = [[controller1-2view itemAtRow:[controller1-2view selectedRow]] representedObject];
        NSString *selectedProjectName = [selectedProject valueForKey:@"title"];

        NSFetchRequest *controller2FetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc= [controller2 managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *controller2Entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityTitle" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        [controller2FetchRequest setEntity:entityTitle];
        NSError *controller2FetchError = nil;
        newArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:controller2FetchRequest error:&controller2FetchError];
        NSInteger projectCounter = 0;
        [controller2FetchRequest release];

        for (NSString *s in newArray) {
            NSManagedObject *projectMo = [newArray objectAtIndex:projectCounter];  // assuming that array is not empty
            id projectValue = [projectMo valueForKey:@"title"];
            //NSLog(@"projectValue is %@ and selectedProjectName is %@", projectValue, selectedProjectName);
            if (projectValue == selectedProjectName) {
                //NSLog(@"Match found");
                [controller2 setSelectionIndex:projectCounter];
                NSLog(@"Selected in arrayController: %@", [controller2Controller selectedObjects]);
            }
            projectCounter = projectCounter + 1;
        }
}
```